# Removing similar characters in a string

Tags: c#, string

Is there any built-in method to remove similar characters in a string?
Examples:

```
aaaabbbccc ->  abc
aabbccaa -> abc
```

Thanks

Comment: what happens to the following string "aabbccaa"

Comment: So you want your string to become a set of characters. Ok, that changes the answer a bit.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a `HashSet` and build an extension method for this:

```
    static string RemoveDuplicateChars(this string s)
    {
        HashSet<char> set = new HashSet<char>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);

        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            if (set.Add(c))
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

or using [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx), simply:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string("aaabbbccaddcacc".Distinct().ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 6):

Does something like this solve your problem?

```
string distinct = new string("aaaabbbccc".Distinct().ToArray());
```

It's a little ugly, but you could wrap it into an extension method:

```
public static string UniqueChars(this string original)
{
    return new string(original.Distinct().ToArray());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the source string is "aaaabbbcccaa" then this method will return "abc", not "abca". It's not clear which outcome the OP expects in that situation.

Comment: By the way, you could shorten your code down to something like this: `string distinct = new string("aaaabbbccc".Distinct().ToArray());`

Comment: That's true. None of the answers to this question are valid without clarification.

Comment: Luke, the OP actually wants `abc` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class:

```
Regex.Replace( "aaabbcc", @"(\w)\1+", "$1" )
```

will result in

```
abc
```

For more infos look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx).

**EDIT:**
Since <s>you</s> I edited your question:

```
Regex.Replace( "acaabbccbaa", @"(\w)(?<=\1.+)", "" )
```

will result in

```
acb
```

This pattern uses a negative lookbehind to identify doubled chars and replaces them by `""`

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought you want to look at using Regular Expressions. For C# .NET this is a useful site...

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Answer (score 0):

no.

But can easly be made in a loop, remember you need to build a new string you cannot edit a char in a existing string ( you can do string.remove , but very likely gonna be slow and mess up your loop ).

basicly:

```
for(int i=0;i<MyText.Length;i++)
{
   if(i == 0)
     contiune;

   if(Text[i] == Text[i - 1])
       // Do something, both chars are the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically asked about removing "similar" characters, you may want to try something like this:

```
using System.Globalization;
....
        private string RemoveDuplicates(string text)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            string previousTextElement = string.Empty;
            TextElementEnumerator textElementEnumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(text);
            textElementEnumerator.Reset();
            while (textElementEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                string textElement = (string)textElementEnumerator.Current;
                if (string.Compare(previousTextElement, textElement, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace |
                    CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth) != 0)
                {
                    result.Append(textElement);
                    previousTextElement = textElement;
                }
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
```